# How to allow capital letter,number in datagridview cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2005

I'm using a datagridview in my windows program. In column 1 user will enter capital letter and number. In some other columns (column 3 and 4) user will enter only integer number(no decimal allowed). I'm writing the following code to convert the entered value into capital letter for column 1: In CellEndEdit event

```
    string strUpper = "";

                switch (e.ColumnIndex)
                {
                    case 1:
                        strUpper = dgView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() ;
                        dgView.CurrentCell.Value = strUpper.ToUpper();
                        break;
                }
```

The entered value is converted to uppercase when focus is moving to next cell. But I want to know is there any other event/code to do the same? And how not to allow user to enter decimal in cell 3 and 4. Please help.

Comment: @AmenAyach There is no such event for datagridview 2005 visual studio version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CellValidating` event of the `DataGridView` like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) {
        // insert additional checks to fit your constraints
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.IsInEditMode) {
            int value;
            if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out value)) {
                MessageBox.Show("Must be integer!");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is doesn't work when `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N0";` ;(